# WPF app crashes while receiving data from Arduino

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, arduino

I am developing a wpf app which will collect sensor data from an Arduino Leonardo. The fact is while sending serial data, there isn't any problem but while reading data, the app seems to freeze. Here is my code.

```
private void connect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        String pno = cno.Text;
        sp.PortName = pno;
        sp.BaudRate = 9600;
        sp.Open();
        s.Text = "Connected";
                    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Please check the com port number or the hardware attached to it");
    }
}

private void go_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    string a = sp.ReadLine();
    Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => receivedblock.Text = a));            
}
```

The go_Click method is a button which when pressed will accept the serial data.

Comment: `sp.Readline()` is a blocking call! so when you call it it waits until it can read a line from `sp` so your app freezes!

Comment: What can be the possible solution? I want to get live data.

Comment: what is the type of `sp`?

Comment: SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://github.com/SolidSoils/Arduino. It's officially still in beta, but it supports observable receivers for serial messages (and more), which is especially handy in WPF apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `sp.ReadLine()` is a blocking call. So when you call it, it waits until it can read a line from `sp` so your app freezes!

You should subscribe to [DataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) event and do your stuff there.